# Cloudfront with External domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, amazon-route53

We are using shopify for our ecommerce store, shopify manages the server and underlining infrastructure.

We are hosting the DNS records in AWS Route53, and are now attempting to add a CDN (AWS Cloudfront) but we are running into errors.

We have tried using the domain name that is provided by shopify which is hosted by them (shopify.mystore-XXXXX.com) when creating the distribution file. Then we took the domain name that AWS creates when creating the cloudfront distribution and made the alias in AWS Route53 to the domain name we are using. example.com --> cloudfrontcdname.com

When doing this we receive this error **"403 the request could not be satisfied"**

*Is it possible to use AWS Cloudfront with external sites outside of AWS?, I am only seeing docs related to AWS hosted resources.*

Comment: Did you add that domain name as an alternate domain name in CloudFront?

Comment: No we did not, which domain name would we add? the domain for our site?

Comment: Yes I suggest you follow the instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html and add your website's domain name (what you call "example.com" in your question) as an alternate domain in your CloudFront distribution.